# finding the maximum number of 1's in a row

Tags: algorithm, matrix, binary-search

> A 2d matrix is given filled with 1's and 0's. It is given that all 1's in a row come before all the 0's. We have to find the maximum number of 1's in a row.

I have made the solution that we can apply binary search on every row to get the last index of last 1 in that row before 0's begin and hence the no. of 1's will be its index+1. So we can do this at every row.
So the complexity would be O(mlogn),where m is the no. of rows and n is the no. of columns.
Can there be a better solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054677/finding-the-maximum-number-of-1s-in-a-row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in O(n+m).

Start with curmax equal to 0.

Then process rows one by one. Increase curmax while there are at least curmax ones in that row, i.e. checking if curmax value is one.

The answer will be curmax-th, after all rows are processed.

This will work in O(n+m).

Will it be quicker than O(m*logn)? It depends. If m is less then n/(log(n) - 1) it will work, actually longer then O(m*log n) and quicker otherwise, just in terms of complexity.
Considering constants is another problem, when approximating time. So for n and m of one magnitude this will be quicker, for different there is only one choice - try both, pick better.

Answer (score 3):

You're only interested in the max, so you don't have to find the position of the switch for every row.

After the first row's switch position is found, k(0), you search the second row starting at position k(0), and if it's a 0, then the second row doesn't contain the longest sequence, so you can ignore where it actually is.  This doesn't improve the worst-case time complexity, but it would improve average case.

Answer (score 3):

The gist of an O(n+m) algorithm is this.

Imagine your matrix as a grid.

Start at the top left corner.

If you are at a 1, move right.  Otherwise move down.

Keep doing this until you pass the last row.

Then your x coordinate is the maximum count of 1's.

You may move one past the last column, if there is a row of all 1's.  Your algorithm needs to cater for this.

Comment: Thanks for the better solution

Answer (score 1):

```
1     bool matrix[100][200];
2     int max = 0, count, x;
3     
4     for(int y=0;y<100;y++){
5         count = 0;
6         x=max; // This would optimize the search times!
7         for(;x<200;x++){
8             if(matrix[y][x] == 0 && count>max){
9                max=count;
10            }
11            else count++;
12        }
13        if(x == 199)break; // Optimization - the end reached
14    }
15
16    // Now the max var contains the maximum number of 1's of a single row in all columns.
```

Instead of walking through each row you just skip the already known positions.
This optimization is implemented on **line 6**.

Comment: @bdares Check my answer. Take a look at the 6-th line. That's the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Just check it in a row and start in the next row from the position where you stopped in the previous row. If its a 0, go to next row else continue checking the row. Repeat the procedure until last row.

Comment: If `n >> m` this might result in worse performance, but can still be a better solution for a lot of the cases.

Comment: It will improve the average case but not the worst case if no. of 1's are placed in increasing order in every row

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the above code, line no 5, i.e, count =0 should come out of first loop as it is wrongly updating the max variable if the maximum number of 1's are not in the first row of matrix.

Correct tested code i have written below :

```
public static int findRowWithMax1s(int arr[][],int m, int n){

    int x,y,count=0,max=0;
    int row = 0;
    for(x=0;x<m;x++) {
        y = max;
        for(;y<n;y++) {
            if(arr[x][y] == 0) {
                max = count;
                row = x;
                break;
            }
            else
                count++;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define R 4
#define C 4

/* A function to find the index of first index of 1 in a boolean array arr[] */
int first(bool arr[], int low, int high)
{
  if(high >= low)
  {
    // get the middle index  
    int mid = low + (high - low)/2; 

    // check if the element at middle index is first 1
    if ( ( mid == 0 || arr[mid-1] == 0) && arr[mid] == 1)
      return mid;

    // if the element is 0, recur for right side
    else if (arr[mid] == 0)
      return first(arr, (mid + 1), high);

    else // If element is not first 1, recur for left side
      return first(arr, low, (mid -1));
  }
  return -1;
}

// The main function that returns index of row with maximum number of 1s. 
int rowWithMax1s(bool mat[R][C])
{
    int max_row_index = 0, max = -1; // Initialize max values

    // Traverse for each row and count number of 1s by finding the index 
    // of first 1
    int i, index;
    for (i = 0; i < R; i++)
    {
       index = first (mat[i], 0, C-1);
       if (index != -1 && C-index > max)
       {
           max = C - index;
           max_row_index = i;
       }
    }

    return max_row_index;
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
    bool mat[R][C] = { {0, 0, 0, 1},
        {0, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    printf("Index of row with maximum 1s is %d n", rowWithMax1s(mat));

    return 0;
}
```